# Implementing RFID with an exisiting system using vb.net and a sql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, automation, rfid

We are currently trying to implement RFID scanners into our process at my facility. We have many places they would be useful for automation but until now we have used vb.net code and human entry for most of everything. We have used some bar code scanners but that is really just mimicking key strokes. I understand how RFID works but making the RFID talk to my VB.net and SQL database is becoming quite complicated. I need to know either a middleware program that can initiate changes in our sql server, or some type of code in vb.net that will allow me to plug a scanner in and use it in conjunction with code. Can anyone point me in a direction or shoot me some freeware programs out there to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of that depends on what type of scanner you're using...for example...if you're using an AML scan gun (with keypad and display screen), then most of these are terminal emulation sessions..i.e. telnet or ssh connections to a server that simply run a application (perl, python, vb, etc).  On the other hand...if you're using the $20 keyboard extension scanner that just 'scans'...then you're probably using that in conjunction with an app on a stand alone PC.  The database interaction within the app is independent of scanner type...but how you deploy it...telnet, ssh, shared app will be dependent of the scanner employed.  We use AML scan guns that essentially invoke a telnet session...running a perl script that does the logic/DB updates within the script...and looping back to 'main menu' until the session is ended...ie that shut it off or control c.  Obviously there's a lot to go into...but I'd start with the type of gun (how much interaction is involved by the enduser)...and let that drive the design from there.